# Are there naming rules in Arxml?

Tags: xml, autosar

I am checking the ‘IPdu Mapping’ in AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate.pdf, IPduMapping in Arxml will be I-PDU-MAPPING，targetIPdu will be TARGET-I-PDU, is there any rules on the name?

Any AUTOSAR document mention this naming convention?

```
<I-PDU-MAPPINGS>
  <I-PDU-MAPPING>
    <SOURCE-I-PDU-REF DEST="PDU-TRIGGERING">/Cluster/CAN/xxxx</SOURCE-I-PDU-REF>
    <TARGET-I-PDU>
      <TARGET-I-PDU-REF DEST="PDU-TRIGGERING">/Cluster/CAN/xxxx</TARGET-I-PDU-REF>
    </TARGET-I-PDU>
  </I-PDU-MAPPING>
</I-PDU-MAPPINGS>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find the answer to your question in chapter 3.6 (named "XML Names") of the AUTOSAR standard document "TPS SchemaProductionRules".

In short, capital letters in the name of a meta-model element (like `IPduMapping`) trigger the existence of a "-" in the XML name in the schema (translating it to `I-PDU-MAPPING`). XML names in the AUTOSAR schema are all-uppercase by convention. There are further rules for numerals, as described in the quoted chapter.

Comment: thanks for your accurate answer, as we have so many AUTOSAR documents, do you have any tips to quickly find the related one or are there any document to introduce the AUTOSAR document/file structure?

Comment: You can find the documentation of the schema production rules [here](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/foundation/20-11/AUTOSAR_TPS_XMLSchemaProductionRules.pdf). In each release, AUTOSAR publishes a [release overview](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/foundation/20-11/AUTOSAR_TR_FoundationReleaseOverview.pdf) where you can get an overview about what happened in the release.